# Find Top rated product in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a Review Model and Product Model such as:

> ```
> const ProductReviewSchema = Schema({
>   rating: {
>     type: Number,
>     min: 1,
>     max: 5,
>     required: true,
>   },
>   product: {
>     type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
>     ref: 'ecommerce-product',
>   },
> });
> ```

and

> ```
> const ProductSchema = Schema({   name: String,   price: Number });
> ```

and I want to display top-rated product I can do this using find method in `reviewschema` and using loops

```
const totalResult = await ProductReviewModel.find({}, 'rating _id');
    let averageRatingNumerator = 0;
    let averageRatingDenominator = 0;
    if (totalResult) {
      totalResult.forEach((eachRate) => {
        averageRatingDenominator += 1;
        averageRatingNumerator += eachRate.rating;
      });
    }
```

then find the average rating of each product and sort the result in ascending order. Can I do the exact same thing using mongoose aggregate, If yes what pipeline or operator should I use to achieve such a result:

My Expected result may be is:

> ```
> [
>   { product: 'abc', avgRating: 3.5 },
>   { product: 'def', avgRating: 3.1 } 
> ];
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search from the `productReview` Schema and populate the `product`,

- `$group` by `product` and get average of `rating`
- `$sort` by `avgRating` in descending order
- `$lookup` and join `product` collection
- `$unwind` deconstruct `product`
- `$project` to show required fields

```
const totalResult = await ProductReviewModel.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$product",
      avgRating: { $avg: "$rating" }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { avgRating: -1 } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "products", // update your actual product collection name
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "product"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$product" },
  {
    $project: {
      name: "$product.name",
      avgRating: 1
    }
  }
]).exec();
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-i0YjO3dGL5)

---

Search from `product` Schema and populate `productReview`,

- `$lookup` join products review collection
- `$size` to get total reviews
- `$sum` to calculate sum of return array of `rating`
- `$let` to specify both (`total`, `ratings`) as variable
- `$cond` check condition if `total` is not zero then `$divide`
- `$sort` by `avgRating` in descending order

```
const totalResult = await Products.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "productsReview", // replace your actual review collection name here
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "product",
      as: "review"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      avgRating: {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            total: { $size: "$review" },
            ratings: { $sum: "$review.rating" }
          },
          in: {
            $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$total", 0] }, 0, { $divide: ["$$ratings", "$$total"] }]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { avgRating: -1 } }
]).exec();
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uyZJF-bpsP0)

Comment: will this give the average rated items or most rated items?

Comment: this will give a list of products with the average of ratting.